# How do I enable mouse scroll wheel zoon in flash screen?

Tags: mouse-scroll, flash

I have just installed Ubuntu.  I have a Logitech M305 mouse.  The mouse works fine in most applications.  When I try to use the mouse wheel to zoom while using a flash application nothing happens.  I have tried using the wheel in combination with various keys, such as Ctrl, Alt, Shift and combinations of those keys, and no luck.  Is there anything I can do to get this working.  Am using Chromium with Adobe Square.

Comment: Usually nothing happens in Firefox either.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards